# I'm having project OpenShop in objective c while running that project (null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDTgF.jpg): This shows exactly whats going on with project and help to resolve it.

I downloaded this project from https://github.com/openshopio/openshop.io-ios,
but I faced some problems when running it.

The first run it showed some pod file missing errors; after, when I updated cocoa pods on my system, and after installing the required pods for the project, it showed a clang error:

> `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I searched for that error hoping to resolve it, but I still can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Need more information

Comment: Please add a code to see certain problem. We cannot guess it.

Comment: I faced the same issue once, but that time I opened the xcode project file instead of the Pod workspace. Not sure about this.

Comment: Try cleaning your project :- `cmd+shift+K`

Comment: @Harjeet What Xcode version you have? And have you opened a workspace file as Sreekanth marked?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into same problem.

Delete file OpenShop.xcworkspace.

Run: POD Install in Terminal.

This will rebuild the project dependencies.

Double click new created OpenShop.xcworkspace.

That should work.